# Add a hidden class for Isotope(Metafizzy)

Tags: javascript, class, jquery-isotope

Rather than hidden items receiving a style of display none how could I instead add a class of hidden?

I'm using vanilla javascript rather than jQuery.

I can find nothing about this in any of the documentation.
Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question; I have searched far and wide for an answer.

Comment: Do you mean using CSS? Because thats how you can make classes with a hidden style.

Comment: The Isotope Javascript (https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) adds inline styles to each Isotope element to be hidden when filtering, so for example I filter by items of type W and all other items X, Y and Z are hidden. I'd rather that functionally the plugin adds a class.